# Explanation on the proof for $\bar{S} = \mathrm{cl } S $.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $S$ be a set and let $\mathcal{A} = \{\mathcal{A_{\alpha}} \, : \, S \subseteq \mathcal{A}_{\alpha} \, \, \mathrm{and} \, \, \mathcal{A}_{\alpha} \, \, \mathrm{is} \, \, \mathrm{closed}\}$ where $\alpha \in A$ and $A$ is a nonempty indexing set.

Let $\bar{S} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} \, A_{\alpha}$, which denotes the intersection of all the closed sets containing $S$.

Here is a picture of the problem with the teacher's solution:

[image]

My question is with regards to the two sentences preceding the last sentence of the teacher's proof. From the assumption that $x \in S'\setminus S$ and that every neighborhood of $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $S$, she quickly concludes that $x \in \mathcal{A}_{\alpha}$ for every $\alpha$. But I do not see how this immediately follows.

Comment: please fix your title ("Explanation of the proof for $)... it seems you are asking the explanation of a proof for money :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is a limit point of $S$.  (that's what every neighborhood of $x$ having a nonempty intersection with $S$ implies.)  So for every $A_{\alpha}$, $S \subset A_{\alpha}$ so every neighborhood of $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $A_{\alpha}$.  So $x$ is a limit point of $A_{\alpha}$.  As $A_{\alpha}$ is closed, $x \in A_{\alpha}$.

===

I think your professor simply forgot to point out $x$ is a limit point of $A_{\alpha}$.  The funny thing is when I typed my answer, I left it out too.  Even though I was thinking that was the *essential* point.

=====

I think a much easier way to put this would be

Lemma 1)  $cl(S) S \cup S'$ is closed.

Lemma 2) If $S \subset A$ and $A$ is closed.  Then $cl(S) \subset A$.

Pf: If $x \in S$ then $x \in A$.  If $x \in S'$ then $x$ is a limit point of $S$ so every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $S$ so every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ as $A$ is a superset of $S$.  So $x$ is a limit point of $A$ so as $A$ is closed, $x \in A$.  So $x \in cl(S) \implies x \in A$ so $cl(S) \subset A$.

Theorem:  As stated.

Proof is now trivial.  $S \subset cl(S)$ closed.  So $cl(S) \in \mathcal A$ so $\overline S = \cap \mathcal A_{\alpha} \subset cl(S)$.

As $cl (S) \subset A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$, $cl (S) \subset \cap \mathcal A_{\alpha}= \overline S$

Comment: Does it matter that the professor said, "every neighborhood of $x$" instead of a deleted neighborhood?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "deleted neighborhood".  But "every neighborhood" implies x is a limit point.  If it were just some neighborhoods x need not be a limit point.